# После обновления WebStorm не работает, вернул старую версию, всё ровно выдает ошибку

Tags: windows-7, webstorm

```
Internal error. Please report to http://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Users\Karen\.WebStorm2019.1\config\port.lock
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:115)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:287)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:335)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.underLocks(SocketLock.java:172)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.lock(SocketLock.java:121)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lockSystemFolders(StartupUtil.java:309)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareAndStart(StartupUtil.java:135)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.lambda$start$0(PluginManager.java:75)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Система Windows 7 32bit. Скачал webstorm2019.1.3. Обновился,новая версия только для 64-битной системы, вернул старую версию, показывает эту табличку. Помогите исправить ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Из сообщения очевидно, что какой-то процесс блокирует доступ к `C:\Users\Karen\.WebStorm2019.1\config\port.lock`. Если перезагрузка системы не помогает, попробуйте выяснить, что это за процесс (возможно, это антивирус, или какая-то backup утилита). Это можно сделать с помощью  **Process explorer**, например - см. http://superuser.com/questions/117902/easy-way-to-find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows

Кстати, неправда, что новую версию нельзя использовать на 32-битных системах. По умолчанию, действительно, продукт поставляется с JRE 11, для которой существует только 64-битная версия. Но Вы можете скачать версию с JBR 8 с https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/download/other.html и в процессе инсталляции выбрать **Download and install JRE x86 by JetBrains** в процессе инсталляции, чтобы поставить 32-битную JRE

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]